# Pan to center and change icon when clicked on a marker with Subgurim Maps and jQuery 

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-maps, subgurim-maps

It is a question regarding [Subgurim Google Maps](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/) wrapper in ASP.NET.

I would like to know if I can do this from a client side:

Click on a button then a using jQuery to pan a marker to center and change its icon (image).

Would it be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can manipulate Google Maps through jQuery. Actually, there are plugins to further simplify that. For example take a look at [Google Maps jQuery Plugin V1.01](http://googlemaps.mayzes.org/) by Shawn Mayzes, or try [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+jquery+plugin) Google search and you'll find many more.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your suggestion. Because i am using subgurim google map wrapper in asp.net so I am looking for a solution with this...